# set "read more..." button to dangerouslySetInnerHTML - React

Tags: reactjs, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I reveive some HTML from an API call, and I would like to display for example the 200 first characters, and create a read more button to display more.

I am using React with TypeScript.

Here is my code :

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: template.content }} className="my-4"></p>

<button className="underline">Lire la suite +</button>
```

I tried react-truncate-html, but to types for TypeScript.

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Is the returned HTML in a consistent/predictable structure?  I would probably look at pulling the useful data out the HTML and re-formatting it into a nice data structure, so you don't have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and your React app retains complete control of the UI rendered. (Or, if you have control of the server, just don't send HTML in the first place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first check length of the content and if greater than 200 then slice the content if not then show the content as it is the second condition for if the content length is greater than 200 then show the button.

```js
<div>
  {template?.content?.length > 200 ?
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: template?.content.slice(0, 200) }} className="my-4"></p>
:
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: template?.content}} className="my-4"></p>
  }
  {template?.content?.length > 200 && <button className="underline">Lire la suite +</button>}
</div>
```